# Understanding windows in Vim

Tags: vim

I have an understanding of buffers, but I am unsure as to how to navigate through windows? I use the Ack plugin and NERDTree. If I search for something in Ack while having both the NERDTree window and my main coding window open, how can I switch between these three different windows?

Occasionally, I accidentally open a file that takes over the NERDTree window, so now I have two windows with code, and one Ack window. Then I have to end up closing the buffer I opened, which ends up closing the window, then reopening NERDTree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can move between windows by doing the following: `Ctrl-w` followed by a directional key, for example `h`, `j`, `k`, or `l` (or by using the corresponding`arrow keys`).

Comment: i tried your suggestion and am getting this: Cannot close last tab page. i shall google this.

Comment: @tipu you've probably mapped `<C-w>` to `:tabclose` to make it more like firefox or other web browsers.  Try checking the output of `:verbose map <C-w>`.

Comment: Note that they are separate key combinations. You can't go ctrl+w+left, for exmple. You have to go ctrl+w RELEASE left.

Comment: @Randy: you were correct. i setup tabs like i was in notepad++. i unmapped and fuggle's explanation works just fine. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you manage to open another buffer in the current window you can use `C-i` and `C-o` to move backwards and forwards in your jump list which should bring you back to your nerdTree buffer I believe (dont use nerdTree myself so can confirmit)